# How to resolve this error? java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json, android-studio, parsing, jsonparser

I am trying to set value for sponsorID to the textview but but I'm not able to parse response to line`etSponsor_name.setText(strSponsorId);`

this is my code

```
TextView sponsorName,etSponsor_name;
String strSponsorId = "";
```

sponsorId.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            strSponsorId = sponsorId.getText().toString();
            String url = Config.URL + "webapi/fortuneapi.asmx/CheckSponcer?SponcerID=" + strSponsorId;
            Log.d("TAG", url);
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.d("TAG", "SponcerID: " + response);


                        try {

                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            strSponsorId = jsonObject.optString("SponsorID","");
                            Log.i("TAG", "parseData: " + strSponsorId);
                            etSponsor_name.setText(strSponsorId);


                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.d("TAG", "SponcerIDException: " + e);
                        }
                        Log.d("TAG", "SponcerID_EX_Response: " + response);

                    }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "onErrorResponse_of_sponcerID: " + error.getMessage());


                }
            });

            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
            queue.add(stringRequest);
        }
    });
```

StackTrace:

```
2022-01-13 15:03:17.755 24864-24864/com.example.fortuinelife D/TAG: https://fortunelife.asia/webapi/fortuneapi.asmx/CheckSponcer?SponcerID=sai
2022-01-13 15:03:18.203 24864-24864/com.example.fortuinelife D/TAG: SponcerID: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Fortune Life</string>
2022-01-13 15:03:18.204 24864-24864/com.example.fortuinelife D/TAG: 
SponcerIDException: org.json.JSONException: Value <?xml of type 
java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Comment: You haven't told us which line of code the error refers to.

Comment: @Michael etSponsor_name.setText(strSponsorId); this line

Comment: That does not help much. Could you please also post `response` from `onResponse` callback? So that it can be verified what _string content_ you are trying to parse into a `JSONObject`.

Comment: And what are the types of `etSponsor_name` and `strSponsorId`?

Comment: @Jay <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Fortune Life</string> check this response

Comment: @Michael plz review question once i have mentioned their.

Comment: Based on the information you've provided it seems unlikely that the error really occurs on the line where you say it occurs. Please post the full stacktrace.

Comment: @Michael done sir pls check.

Comment: Well, why are you passing a string containing XML into the `JSONObject` constructor? What are you trying to do here exactly?

Comment: @Michael just want to set that response to the textview.

Comment: `response` is already a `String`, so why not just pass that directly to `setText`?

Comment: @Michael i tried this but it takes full response like  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Fortune Life</string>` i want only `Fortune Life` Text